# lapply in list - setting rownames to NULL

Tags: r

I have a list as shown below. Now I'm trying to set all the rownames in each data.frame of my list to `NULL`, so that each data.frame start with 1 as it's rowname. But somehow it doesn't execute correctly.

Something is wrong with my lapply statement, but I can't figure out what.

Code

```
  20function  <- function (return.query) {

  by.areaSize  <- split(return.query, return.query$areaSize, drop = FALSE)

  lapply(by.areaSize, FUN = function(x) rownames(x)  <- NULL)


  return(by.areaSize)
}
```

List I'm applying lapply to

```
summary(x.split)
    Length Class      Mode
0   28     data.frame list
10  28     data.frame list
20  28     data.frame list
30  28     data.frame list
40  28     data.frame list
50  28     data.frame list
60  28     data.frame list
70  28     data.frame list
80  28     data.frame list
90  28     data.frame list
100 28     data.frame list
110 28     data.frame list
120 28     data.frame list
130 28     data.frame list
140 28     data.frame list
150 28     data.frame list
160 28     data.frame list
170 28     data.frame list
180 28     data.frame list
190 28     data.frame list
200 28     data.frame list
210 28     data.frame list
220 28     data.frame list
230 28     data.frame list
250 28     data.frame list
260 28     data.frame list
270 28     data.frame list
280 28     data.frame list
300 28     data.frame list
330 28     data.frame list
```

Still after my lapply, the rownames in each data.frame does not start with 1, as intended. But by their index number from the `split function`, respectively.

Comment: You need a return (x) i.e. `lapply(by.areaSize, FUN = function(x) {rownames(x)  <- NULL);x })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop; there's no need for `lapply()` here:

```
list.of.dfs <- list(`0`=data.frame(a=1:3,b=letters[1:3],row.names=rnorm(3)),`10`=data.frame(x=4:6,y=letters[4:6],row.names=rnorm(3)));
list.of.dfs;
## $`0`
##                    a b
## 0.0498607222485908 1 a
## 0.97522800355155   2 b
## 0.128524519534542  3 c
##
## $`10`
##                    x y
## -0.869665657970296 4 d
## 1.45087559347205   5 e
## 0.70259805976925   6 f
##
summary(list.of.dfs);
##    Length Class      Mode
## 0  2      data.frame list
## 10 2      data.frame list
for (i in seq_along(list.of.dfs)) rownames(list.of.dfs[[i]]) <- NULL;
list.of.dfs;
## $`0`
##   a b
## 1 1 a
## 2 2 b
## 3 3 c
##
## $`10`
##   x y
## 1 4 d
## 2 5 e
## 3 6 f
##
```

---

Let me try to explain what's going on in your code. Firstly, it's important to understand R scope rules. Every invocation of any function causes an evaluation environment to be created for that particular function evaluation, and all local variables assigned during that function evaluation are stored in that environment. Function parameters are also stored in that environment. The lambda of an `lapply()` call is no different from any other function. In your case, this means the `x` parameter of your lambda becomes a new local variable for each evaluation of the lambda, IOW for each element of the original list `by.areaSize`. Making changes to the `x` variable has no effect on the original list `by.areaSize`, because `by.areaSize` is a separate variable which is local to the outer function's evaluation environment (referring to your function `20function()`).

If you really want to use `lapply()` to accomplish this task, there are two approaches you can take. First, you can iterate over the *indexes* (or names) of the original list, rather than its elements, and index-assign the original list using the superassignment operator `<<-`, which searches through the closure environment chain until it finds a match for the LHS variable name (or, if none is found, will create a new such variable in the global environment). This is similar to what I did above with my `for` loop, except I didn't have to use the superassignment operator there because I didn't have an inner function scope to worry about. Here's how this would look:

```
lapply(seq_along(by.areaSize),function(x) rownames(by.areaSize[[x]]) <<- NULL);
```

Alternatively, you can overwrite the entire original list with the return value of the `lapply()` call, which would allow you to effectively "rebuild" the list with whatever values you return from the lambda. In your case, you would want to modify the row names of `x` and then return `x` itself. Currently, your lambda is actually returning the return value of the local assignment operation, which is the value of the RHS, which is NULL in your case. Obviously that's not what you want. Here's how to do this:

```
by.areaSize <- lapply(by.areaSize,function(x) { rownames(x) <- NULL; x; });
```